# get all files from a directory without details

Tags: linux, ls

I discovered that

```
ls -AF /var/ |grep \/$
```

helps me to find all directories from a directories without more information.
Now i need exactly the opposite - showing all files without any further information just the file name in each line

```
file1
file2
file3
```

and filtering the directories because those - i don't need

Comment: @piokuc And how would the manpage for `ls` help in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For finding files matching a certain expression there exists `find`. Its man-page is quite good and includes also some interesting examples. For getting only the files of a directory you can use:

```
find /var -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 54):

Simplest way: its not L its digit - 1

```
$ ls -1
```

Comment: this also includes directories

Comment: @Shaunak-Sontakke you saved my sanity. Confirmed this works as described on bash on MacOS Monterey.

Comment: @yellowsir if you pass a "\*.\*" at the end you will get rid of the directories.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `-v` switch for `grep` to invert the match:

```
ls -AF /var/ |grep -v /$
```

Answer (score 3):

`ls -1Ap /var/ | grep -v /`

Similar to @choroba's answer, but this version will list clean file names on each line *without* appending additional classification indicators, if you don't want them.

-p  flag appends / to directories

-1  flag is always handy to list one file per line

Answer (score -1):

Or use find :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f /var/
```

Comment: Several issues with that command. The path is missing, `-maxdepth` has to come before `-type`, and it does not give what the OP wants (show only filenames without the path)

Comment: `path` is not mandatory, but you need `-maxdepth` before `-type`

Comment: path is required if you the target directory is not pwd, which appears to be the case in this question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have a terminal available to test. Lothar Krause's answer is better anyway, didn't think the trailing / and beginning ./ were going to be a problem for the OP.